# Find $n$ such that integral of $f(x) = 0.99, 0.98, 0.97, \ldots$ where $f(x) = x^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I find that for $f(x)=x^{1/n}$, as $n$ grows larger, the area under its curve (from $0$ to $1$) approaches $1$.

- if $n = 99$, then area $= 0.99$,
- if $n = 49$, then area $= 0.98$,
- if $n = 32+1/3$ then area $= 0.97$,
- if $n = 24$ then area $= 0.96$, etc.

I found those through brute force, using an integral calculator, but rather than plugging random values in for $n$ until I find all 99 values, is there another way to find which values of $n$ will give me exactly the areas: $0.95, 0.94, 0.93, \ldots, 0.01$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing $\int_0^1 x^{\frac 1n} dx=\left.\frac n{n+1}x^{\frac {n+1}n}\right|_0^1=\frac n{n+1}$

For area $A$, then, you want $A=\frac n{n+1}, (n+1)A=n, n=\frac A{1-A}$

Comment: How succinct! Thank you. That is, if A = 0.95, then n = 0.95/(1-0.95) = 0.95/0.5 = 19, so the area under the curve f(x) = x^(1/19) has an area of 0.95!